# How to serve content from different directory for sub domains

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to serve contents from different directory for virtual sub domains.

Ex: `http://www.website.com` gets its content from `www` directory.

for `virtual.company.com` i want to serve content from `/www/application` directory.

And i want to keep the url parameter same.

I have already created php files to display custom message based on the sub-domain., But i am having problems with htaccess,

In simple i just want to load content for subdomains from different directory other than the root directory.

Comment: Guys, it's not just for 1 dub-domain, but for all sub-domains other than www, i..e for all sub-domains other than www i want to serve content from /www/application/ directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.company\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.company\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /application/%1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It's not just for virtual subdomain, it's for all subdomain other than www.

Comment: +1 Hmmmmm, that seems better than my solution. Still wouldn´t recommend it though...

Comment: @Roccos - updated to change for anything other than `www`.  But would each subdomain/host have it's own directory, or are they all mapped to one directory?

Comment: They all are mapped to 1 directory, but the index page gets the subdomain name (via php functions) and displays the data accordingly (from the database).

Comment: It's just that i am going to provide a SAAS Solution, everything is ready and i want to provide custom url's to my clients but i don't know how htaccess works.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn´t sound like a very good idea as people could enter `http://www.website.com/application` and that might lead to unwanted results. I would recommend setting up a virtual host for `virtual.company.com` and separate the two.

However, it is possible and it would be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^virtual\.company\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.company.com/application/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That is going to do a redirect though, which probably isn't what he wants.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje, yes, I just saw your answer and that seems better, I´m not that fluent in *htaccess* :-)

Answer (score 0):

Setup a named virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sub.domain.com
  DocumentRoot "/path/to/sub/domain"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName another.domain.com
  DocumentRoot "/path/to/another/sub/domain"
</VirtualHost>
```